# Calculate/Compare Imrovement Rate from data using Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, data-analysis

I have two set of datas (A and B), just like the following graph. 
And I want to find improvement/increasement rate for both.

[Data Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEzuG.png)

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o48Vc.png)

If i just calculate using the growth rate using the data from the 1st and the 10th, the result would end up the same for A and B since they both start and end with the same number.

What i want to do is to take all of the datas into account - and say that the Data A > Data B in terms of improvement (since A improves rapidly at the start while B improves slower).

I got an advice that I should look into using Differential equation, and I searched for it. And I did get the brief idea of Differential equation (getting a slope at one particular point of data).
But how am I supposed to incorporate this equation so that I can get the improvement rate from this set of datas?